# My simple prolog code is throwing an syntax error: operator expected

Tags: prolog, syntax-error

As the title suggest, my prolog code is throwing a syntax error. Im not sure what Im doing wrong. Im using Swi for my IDE and I tried playing with it to fix the problem, but to no avail. 
heres my simple prolog code with error

```
?- 
|    male(bob)
|    male(jeff)
|    
|    female(jane)
|    female(erica)
|    
|    father(bob,jane)
|    mother(erica, jane)
|    
|    ?-mother(erica,X).
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: male(bob)
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: 
male(jeff)

female(jane)
female(erica)

father(bob,jane)
mother(erica, jane)

?-mother(erica,X) .
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two phases of Prolog development: Writing the program and interacting with it in the Prolog shell. These two phases are separate. You don't write your program in the shell, at least not directly.

Save your facts in a file called `family.pl` (with a dot `.` at the end of each fact!), then start the Prolog shell. In the shell, you can load the program using

```
?- consult(family).
```

or

```
?- consult('family.pl').
```

Note that in the first case you leave off the `.pl` extension, but in the second case, if you do use the extension, you should use single quotes (`'`) around the file name.

Now you can run your query:

```
?- mother(erica, X).
X = jane.
```

There are some other ways to load files, such as putting the file name between square brackets `[]` instead of using `consult`, or (for many Prolog systems) simply adding the file name on the command line.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that. Will I be able to run rules in the prolog shell as well?

Comment: If you define rules like `grandmother_of(Grandmother, Grandchild) :- ... .` in your source file, they you will be able to run queries like `grandmother_of(erica, Grandchild)` in the Prolog shell.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, where would I save the source file?

Comment: Wherever you like. You may need to specify a full path name, e.g., `consult('C:\Documents\...\foo.pl')` or `consult('/home/henry/foo.pl')`. On SWI-Prolog on Windows, you can also just double-click `.pl` files, apparently. See http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=quickstart

Answer (score 0):

Statements in prolog end with a dot:

```
male(jeff).
female(jane).
female(erica).
father(bob,jane).
mother(erica, jane).
```

Comment: I tried doing that but I get this error: ERROR: Undefined procedure: male/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)

Comment: Don't you mean: "Terms in Prolog end with a dot"